# How can i download nsdata to memory with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i enjoy working with AFNetworking 2.0 and i'm stuck on how i can download a file to memory. So far i only know how i can download it to a filepath.

An example without afnetworking would be the synchronous call,

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someurl];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is asynchronous call:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:someURL];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // You have it.
}
```

Don’t use *AFNetworking* if you can’t do this.